# Hide subtasks in task list by default

Tags: tasks

I'm trying to find a way to hide the subtasks in a view by default.  I've tried a few javascripts and snippets and can't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any out of the box way for doing this. Using JavaScript you can achieve this by

1. Find all div which has class = itx
2. Do a loop of those div and for each item check the SPAN inside has style Margin-Left = 0; If its 0 then that means its PARENT else its a SubTask
3. Now you can get the Parent TR of that item and hide it

Try the below sample

```
jQuery('div[class="ms-vb  itx"]').find('span[style]').each(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).css('margin-left')!="0px"){
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().hide();
    }
});
```